# Biztalk - iterating through a csv file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a csv file that I iterate through each record and process each one individually. During the process of iterating through the records, each row in the CSV ends up being a message with no namespace; therefore I cannot use the message in a map. To resolve the face that I have no namespace in my message, I write the message to a local string variable, and then do some string manipulation to add the namespace.  There has to be a better way to iterate through a csv file and process each record.

Here is a more detailed description of my issue:
I have a csv file that I need to read, and then perform a series of tasks on each record.  The route that I chose to take to process each record is to determine the number of records in the csv file and then loop through each record by performing this xpath command: 
    “Message_SingleRecord = xpath(Message_Document, "//processingItem[" + counterString + "]");”. 
This works fine to give me each record except for the fact that since the “processingItem” element is essentially a child record of the csv docment, each Message_SingleRecord has no namespace, so I can’t transform/map it.  To get the namespace added to Message_SingleRecord, I created this horrible hack:

```
Debug_SingleMessage = Message_SingleRecord;
debugVariable = Debug_SingleMessage.OuterXml;
debugVariable = debugVariable.Replace("<processingItem xmlns=\"\"", 
    "<ns0:processingItem     xmlns:ns0=\"http://SchemaGeneration.ProcessingSingleRecord\">");
debugVariable = debugVariable.Replace("</processingItem>", "</ns0:processingItem>");
xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(debugVariable);
Message_SingleRecord = xmlDoc;
```

Comment: Why can't you Dissassemble the .csv in either the Receive Pipeline or the Orchestration?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flat File Disassembler to disassembler the CSV file into XML without doing any custom logic. See the link for more details. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577898.aspx